# Optimal formula to predict product when one of the components is certain

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

When an item is clicked, it generates revenue equal to the cost per click (CPC). As such, `revenue = I(click) x CPC`. I want to select the item with highest expected revenue to be shown. I have a machine learning model that predicts the probability of click (eCTR). The obvious idea would be to rank by `expected revenue = eCTR x CPC`.

However, CPC is certain, whereas the click isn't. As such, even if the eCTR model is calibrated, my intuition is that CPC should be given precedence. If it's a calibrated yet high-loss classifier, it may be beneficial to rely more on the (certain) CPC.

Am I wrong in believing a formula such as `revenue = root(eCTR) x CPC` may perform better in generating more revenue than the unbiased `revenue = eCTR x CPC`? What's the math?

Comment: I believe you are risk averse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion. You won't generate more revenue in expectation, but maybe your worst case performance will be better